# vb.net memory overflow without error trap using listview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, memory-management

I have the following code that is crashing:

```
    Try
        Logger.Warn("do_databind entered.")
        Session("AgentId") = AgentId
        Session("section") = Section
        SectionId.Value = Section.ToString()
        Session("dtresponses") = dtresponses
        Session("dtlv") = dtlv
        lvQuestions.DataSource = dtlv
        Logger.Warn("just before databind.")
        lvQuestions.DataBind()
        Logger.Warn("databind successful. ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.Error(ex)
        If Not IsNothing(ex.InnerException) Then
            Logger.Error(ex.InnerException)
        End If
    End Try
```

The coding reaches the "just before databind" message, and then the application aborts.  The "databind successful" message is never reached.

The catch loop is never reached because the error message in it is not recorded.

This has been working for months, and just quit working today.  I would think it is a server problem.

The listview size at the point of the databind command is only 8 records, and I know the page it generates takes less than 10k total with a number of other blocks it generates.

In the old days, we would say this is probably a heap-stack collision, but I am not sure that terminology applies as well to managed memory in VB.Net.  The code that traps the error is probably being overwritten.  Other than that, I have no clue as to why it would stop working on our servers overnight.

Has anyone encountered this particular problem before?

UPDATE:  The server indicates that it is a stack overflow error in w3wp.exe with error code 0xc00000fd (i.e., stack overflow)

[image: error description]

Comment: Do the `DataBinding` and/or `DataBound` events of the `ListView` do something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the databinding or databound events for anything, but it would be an additional diagnostic to see where the memory crash may be occurring.

This app is in testing, so I have extensive error-trapping and comment logging at this point to make sure that the functions are working correctly.

The error does not leave a trace in the program.  It is being caught by the server.  This makes sense if the error is caused by a stack overflow.  It is overwriting the catch code.

UPDATE:

Found the problem.

The program depends on a database, and a change was made to the database that resulted in a recursive procedure that called itself with the same information.

It ran until all the system memory on the server was consumed, and then aborted with a stack overflow error.

I put in diagnostic messages until I finally found it.

The trick here is it was on the staging server, and the database on the development server was not identical, so it worked on the development server the correct way but bombed on the staging server because the database contents were different.

I thought my coding had accounted for the condition that led to the error, but it had not.

Now I know to look for recursive problems if I get an abort in an application that is loaded with try-catch loops and results in no error logging where error logging should exist.